# Change div style upon click

Tags: jquery, styles, background-position

I've got a div say `<div style="background-position: 50% 0"></div>`.

What I want is to increase `background-position` 50% more each time I click on it, i.e. `<div style="background-position: 100% 0"></div>`, then `<div style="background-position: 150% 0"></div>` and so on. is there a way to do that with jquery?

Comment: use .css() function to achieve this

Comment: Your question title says "Change font style upon click" while your question asks about background-position? :)

Comment: ya, please edit title or question...

Comment: sorry, too many things on my mind ;-) changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.animate()` jquery method:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '+=50%'
    },0);
});
```

Comment: this actually worked out. thanks! accordingly, if I'd want to reduce 50% I'll have to change it to '-=50%', right?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/YfKAB/)</kbd>

```
$('div').click(function () {
    var perc = parseInt($(this).attr('style').match(/\d+%/g)) + 50;
    $(this).attr('style', "background-position: " + perc + "% 0");
});
```

---

or

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/YfKAB/1)</kbd>

```
$('div').click(function () {
    var perc = parseInt($(this).attr('style').match(/\d+%/g)) + 50;
    $(this).css("background-position", perc + "% 0");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').css('background-position', function (i, value) {
    var x = parseInt(value, 10);
    return (x + 50) + "%" + " 0";
});
```